# How can I create a WorldBorder using PocketMine-MP?

Tags: php, pocketmine

I'm trying to make a world border by getting player coordinate and stopping them from moving past that coordinate. What should I do? Using Pocketmine 4.0.0

I've tried to find a method to get the coordinates but I don't know what to do.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PlayerMoveEvent.

`use pocketmine\event\player\PlayerMoveEvent;`

```php
public function onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent $event) : void{
    $player = $event->getPlayer();
    $world = $player->getWorld();
    $dat = $this->getConfig()->get("border");

    if(isset($dat[$world->getDisplayName()])){
        $v1 = new Vector3($world->getSpawnLocation()->getX(), 0, $world->getSpawnLocation()->getZ());
        $v2 = new Vector3($player->getLocation()->getX(), 0, $player->getLocation()->getZ());

        if($v2->distance($v1) >= $dat[$world->getDisplayName()]){
            $event->cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

This will get the coordinates of the player and set the border from the world spawn.

Then in your configuration file:

```yaml
border:
  # world-name: border-size
  world: 1000
```

You can add as many world's as needed. However, some hacked clients can bypass this method.